# RabbitMQ Non-Round Robin Dispatching

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, rpc, distributed-computing, amqp

I'm interested in implementing the "Work Queues" model in RabbitMQ. However, I find that the broker does a simple round-robin based dispatching of tasks to workers.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

If a particular worker is busy doing a very heavy task and there are other free workers, the broker should be able to dispatch messages in queue to the **next available worker** and **not the next worker in** round-robin sequence. Is there a way to accomplish this using RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for Fair dispatch (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) based on QoS.

```
channel.basicQos(1);
```

Using a QoS(1) one consumer is busy until doesn’t send the `ACK`,in this case another message is send to the next free consumer.

So if a consumer has a long process to do, it doesn’t receive messages.

If there are not a free consumers the messages remain to the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I was looking for something like Fair dispatch.